# How do I force PM2 to use the latest version of my app?

Tags: pm2

I first invoked PM2 with `pm2 start index.js --watch --ignore-watch "node_modules"`. However, despite telling it to watch my files for changes and then reload, it is not using the latest version of my app when I pull from git.

To test this:

```
$ git show
new version commit message

$ pm2 describe index | grep comment
old version commit message
```

So PM2 is using a cached version.

I tried to reload the app manually, using `pm2 reload index`:

```
$ pm2 reload index
[PM2] Applying action reloadProcessId on app [index](ids: 0)
[PM2] [index](0) ✓
```

However, it's still not using the latest version of my app. `pm2 describe index | grep comment` shows exactly the same old version commit message.

The only way I am able to get it to work is running `pm2 kill` and then `pm2 resurrect`, but that's not a satisfactory solution. It's too slow!

Is PM2 doing some caching? I've read through all of their docs and done an extensive search but can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing this appears to be a bug in PM2's *reporting* of the git commit. The version being served is actually the latest version, but PM2 is reporting the out-of-date one. [Bug report published.](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4666)